# How to remove the scrollbar without scrolling the content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I have a website that uses dialogs. When I open that dialogs the `body` scrollbar is hidden and the scrollbar of the `div` that contains the dialog shows its scrollbar.

*But*, when I hide the `body` scrollbar, the content moves to the begining. How do I keep the position of the content when the dialog is opened?

For more information about this question, look the photos on Facebook. When you click a photo, I like to do that.

Comment: Could it be scrolling to the top because the link you are clicking has a (probably empty) URL fragment identifier like this: `<a href="#">...</a>` ...and the javascript to handle the "dialog" isn't cancelling the event?

Comment: How about showing us a code snippet? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Are you saying that the viewport scrolls back to the top of the body contents, or that the body content itself is shifted upward due to the added extra width freed up by removing the scrollbar?

Comment: I solved using CSS only, using HTML tag with BODY tag combination.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give us the code you are using or a link to the site you are talking about? How are you hiding the scroll bar?

If it is by changing the overflow style property to hidden then am I correct in guessing that this only occurs the first time you show the dialog and subsequent appearances of the dialog do not move the content back to the top? If so I am not sure of the best way to prevent this but a quick hack would be to get your javascript to assign the overflow style property of the 'body's container div to auto upon loading.

Add the following to the top of your javascript:

```
window.onload = function ()
{
    document.getElementById('container').style.overflow = 'auto';
}
```

where container is the id of the div containing your 'body' code.

---

Answer (score 0):

try to use JavaScript to move the scroll to position: 
      `document.getElementById('container').scrollTop = 50;`

above will move scroll bar 50pix to the top, and you can get the max scroll height by:
     `document.getElementById('container').scrollHeight`

Answer (score -1):

Wait, I can't understand your question to well. If you wish to hide the scrollbars, use CSS to hide them.

```
<style type="text/css">
  selector {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
</style>
```